# Why do turbofans go faster than turboprops?

Tags: airspeed, turbofan, turboprop, thrust-reverser, fuel-consumption

Can someone explain why turboprops are less effective in terms of thrust than turbofans? But at the same time, why turboprops burn less fuel? For example, the Bombardier Q400/De Havilland Dash 8 has a fuel burn of 2.79L/seat/100km, whilst the 737 MAX 8 with the same number of engines burns 2.93L/seat/100km, but the Bombardier has a max. cruising speed of 360 knots and the Boeing plane can go up to 526-527 knots, even though it's heavier.

Comment: Most, if not all, turboprops can put the propellers in beta and generate reverse thrust.

Comment: For your second question: [How does propellers' pitch change during the use of reverse thrust in turboprop/propfan propelled planes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59249/14897) -- and [others](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=turboprop+reverse) -- Note: it's advised to [search the site before asking](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Because they are attached to faster airplanes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a given thrust, a turbofan accelerates less air but faster than a turboprop. This means that turbofans can fly faster. However thermodynamically it is more efficient to accelerate a greater mass of air slower, so turboprops are more efficient and that translates into lower fuel burn.

Answer (score 2):

It’s all dependent upon what operating speeds your aircraft will be in.  Propellers can move a great volume of air at slow speeds but accelerate the gas to a lower exit speed than does a turbojet or a turbofan.  This is the principal reason that a helicopter is the most efficient means of VTOL flight out there for a heavier than air aircraft.  But as speeds increase, the the specific impulse drops and the propeller efficiency drops off with it.  At around 400-500 mph, the specific impulse of a high bypass turbofan becomes superior to the turboprop, as, while it moves less air than a turboprop, it can accelerate the smaller air mass to a much higher exit velocity.  This trend continues through low bypass turbofan engines, turbojets and then ramjets.

And as pointed out turboprops have a beta and reverse pitch range which can produce reverse thrust.

Answer (score 0):

Turboprops are less fast because of the mechanical constrainsts at the blade tips,efficiency and noise near the speed of sound.

For reverse thrust:yes

related : 
[How does a turboprop engine keep running during thrust reversal?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43624/how-does-a-turboprop-engine-keep-running-during-thrust-reversal&ved=2ahUKEwiBn8Ct_vnoAhWKBGMBHa-dD5MQFjAgegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1yGArRs8Fn6s9XeWzEjiF8)